# MSSQL subquery result to show and calculate

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I need show a subquery result and use this same result to calculate other value, is possible set this value in a variable in MS SQL 2008 or something like this?
exemple:

```
SELECT
    @test = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tableTest] WHERE [tableTest].[columnA] = [tableA].[columnA]) as 'Counter'
    , (@test * 50) as 'Calc'
    , [tableA].[columnA]
FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use a cte and join on it.

```
with cte as (select count(*) cnt, columnA from [tableTest] group by columnA)
select 
   c.cnt as 'Counter',
   c.cnt * 50 as 'Calc',
   a.columnA
from tableA a
join cte c on c.columnA = a.columnA
```

It could also be done with a subquery, of course

```
select 
  a.columnA,
  c.cnt as 'Counter',
  c.cnt * 50 as 'Calc'
from tableA a
join (select columnA, count(*) as cnt
      from tableTest
      group by columnA) c
  on c.columnA = a.columnA
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you do this. Move the `subquery` outside of `select` statement and store the result in a `variable`

Then use that variable for calculations.

```
declare @test int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tableTest]) 

SELECT
    @test as 'Counter'
    , (@test * 50) as 'Calc'
    , [tableA].[columnA]
FROM tableA
```

**Update :**

```
SELECT [Counter],
       ( [Counter] * 50 ) AS 'Calc',
       columnA
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT Count(*)
                FROM   [tableTest]
                WHERE  [tableTest].[columnA] = [tableA].[columnA]) AS 'Counter',
               [tableA].[columnA]
        FROM   tableA) A
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot a where clause in subquery, it's not possible =/

Comment: @AndrehOdon - variable cannot hold more than one row. what are you really trying to achieve

Comment: @AndrehOdon -  Updated check now

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [correlated sub-queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT 
   Counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableTest t WHERE t.columnA = a.columnA),
   Calc    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableTest t WHERE t.columnA = a.columnA) * 50,
   a.columnA
FROM tableA a
```

It'll be optimized to be only evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT  t2.[Count]
       ,t2.[Count] * 50 As [Calc]
       ,[tableA].[columnA]
FROM TableA 
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
   FROM TableTest
   WHERE [tableTest].[columnA] = [tableA].[columnA]
) t2
```